# GetSchema("ProcedureParameters") would require what permissions?

Tags: c#, .net

We are using the `GetSchema("ProcedureParameters")` to retrieve the schema info of all procedures on a server. When I pass the test server as connection I get the info correctly. when I use the prod server I don't get any o/p.
Can someone tell me what permissions are required to be able to use this method?

And any info what base tables this method use to give us the output in case we pass `ProcedureParameters` as parameter?

Comment: if the db is empty, how can you expect a schema?

Comment: Hey Amit.. I meant the data table is not getting populated and empty. below is the exact code used:


 Data.DataTable table = new Data.DataTable();
//declare the connection
 table = connection.GetSchema("ProcedureParameters");